# Saving Two Integers From The Same TextView

Tags: java, android, storing-data

I have created a stopwatch consisting of hours, minutes and seconds. Ideally, I want the user to click on a button when they wish to stop the stopwatch, saving the time's value. I need this integer to be stored.

The next time the user does this, the int will be stored again, not overwriting the existing int stored from before, as I need two integers. So now there should be two integers, stored in a database or something like SharedPrefences.

**How would this be achievable, considering it's from the same TextView?**

Thanks

Comment: You just need a way to know if the integer you are saving when the button is clicked happens when the stopwatch is running or stopped. This is easily achievable with a boolean field. If stopped, the integer is the start-time, if running is the stop-time.

Comment: Use two different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an ArrayList and each time you grabbing those integers, store them inside an ArrayList, and afterward they can be retrieved to store any where as elements 0 and 1.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    //calling this below each time hitting the button
    int theInt=Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString());
    integerArrayList.add(theInt);
```